# cocos2d-x TouchEvent Remove the Sprite of the SameColor

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-x

I'm creating a tap game now.
So, The Target Sprite is Random Color is created one Sprite.
And I want to erase the sprite of the same color as the target from sprite placed randomly 8 x 8.
But, When user touch the spirit, I'm not possible to get, if the sprite is same color as the target sprite.

Is it possible to determine whether the same color sprite and user target is tapped How do I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to find the sprite which is tapped on.

If you make a layer for that game sprites only and put them on that layer, then it will become easier.

Like this

```
CCSprite * GameScene::findSpriteWithPoint(CCPoint pos)
{
    CCArray *children = m_pGameLayer->getChildren(); 
    //make sure that there's only game sprites on the m_pGameLayer
    CCSprite *child;

    CCSprite *found = NULL;

    if (children) {
        CCARRAY_FOREACH(children, child)
        {
            if (child->boundingBox().containsPoint(pos) == true) {
                found = child;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return found;
}
```

This function will return either found sprite or NULL.

Please NOTE that you need to convert touch location to GL location before call this function .

Like below

```
CCPoint location = touch->getLocationInView();

location = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(location);
CCSprite * found = findSpriteWithPoint(location);
```

Second, just compare the color of found sprite with target sprite.

```
if (found != NULL) {
    ccColor3B color = found->getColor();
    ccColor3B target = m_pTarget->getColor();

    if (color.r == target.r && color.g == target.g && color.b == target.b ) {
        //The color is same
    }
}
```

The comparing method will only works when you made a colored sprite using setColor function.

So, if you want work with natively colored sprites, use user data member of CCSprite as color tags and compare it instead of compare the color itself.

Comment: Hi, onnlv.
Thank you for explanation polite!